# Reason for no simple way to determine 3D coordinate of screen coordinate in Open GL ES 2.0 Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

My question comes from **why** OpenGL and/or Android does not have a way to simply grab the current matrix and store it as a float[]. All the research I have found suggests using these classes which it looks like I have to download and put in my project called **MatrixGrabber** to be able to grab the current state of the Open GL matrix.

My overall goal is to *easily* determine what the Open GL world location is of an event caused by touching the screen where I can retriever the X and Y coordinates by the event.

The best **workaround** I have found is [Android OpenGL 3D picking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699387/android-opengl-3d-picking). but I wonder why there isn't a way where you can simply retriever the matrices you want and then just call

```
GLU.gluUnProject(...);
```

Answer (score 4):

> My question comes from why OpenGL and/or Android does not have a way to simply grab the current matrix and store it as a float[].

Because OpenGL ES 2.0 (and core desktop GL 3.1 and above) do not necessarily *have* a "current matrix." All transforms are done via shader logic, so matrices don't even have to be involved. It could be doing anything in there.

There is no current matrix, so there is nothing to get. And nothing to unproject.

Answer (score 0):

In ES 1 you can grab the current matrix and store it as a float using [`glGetFloatv`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glGet.xml), with the `pname` `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX`, `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX` or `GL_TEXTURE_MATRIX` as applicable.

GLU is not inherently part of OpenGL ES because ES is intended to be a minimal specification and GLU is sort of an optional extra. But you can grab [SGI's reference implementation of GLU](http://www.mesa3d.org/glu.html) and use its `gluUnProject` quite easily.

EDIT: and to round off the thought, as Nicol points out there's no such thing as the current matrix in ES 2. You supply to your shaders arbitrarily many matrices for arbitrarily many purposes, and since you supplied them in the first place you shouldn't need to ask GL to get them back again.

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/spritetext/MatrixGrabber.html which looks like the MatrixGrabber you're referring to and it doesn't look especially complicated — in fact, it's overbuilt. You can just use `gl2.getMatrix` directly and plug that into gluUnProject.

The probable reason for the design of the MatrixGrabber code is that it caches the values for multiple uses — because the GPU runs asynchronously to the CPU, your code may have to wait for the `getMatrix` response, so it is more efficient to get it as few times as possible and reuse the data.

Another source of complexity in the general problem is that a touch specifies only *two* dimensions. A single touch does not indicate any depth, so you have to do that in some application-specific way. The obvious approacj is to read the depth buffer (though some OpenGL implementations don't support that), but that doesn't work if you have e.g things that should be "transparent" to touches. An alternative is to construct a ray (such as by unprojecting twice with two different depths) and then do raycasting into your scene.