# OpenGL: gluUnProject returns wrong coordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es, ray-picking

I set up my scene (Android app, OpenGL ES) like this:

```
GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 60, viewRatio, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
// ...
GLU.gluLookAt(gl, cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ, cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ - 1f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
// Scene scaled down because object positions are in [-10000..10000] for x & y
gl.glScalef(0.001f, 0.001f, 1.0f);
```

The scene is rendered well, it contains quads at z=-10 and one giant background quad at z=-30. I am now trying to implement ray picking, like this (taken from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699387/android-opengl-3d-picking):

```
public float[] unproject(float rx, float ry, float rz) {
    float[] xyzw = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    int[] viewport = {0, 0, mDisplayWidth, mDisplayHeight};
    android.opengl.GLU.gluUnProject(rx, ry, rz, mMatrixGrabber.mModelView, 0, mMatrixGrabber.mProjection, 0, viewport, 0, xyzw, 0);
    xyzw[0] /= xyzw[3];
    xyzw[1] /= xyzw[3];
    xyzw[2] /= xyzw[3];
    xyzw[3] = 1;
    return xyzw;
}
```

Taps onto the screen are then tested this way:

```
unproject(tapX, mDisplayHeight - tapY, BACKGROUND_Z);
```

Expected behaviour: Returned X,Y coordinates resemble the tapped point at depth = -30 (BACKGROUND_Z)

What it actually does: Returns correct X,Y coordinates when tapped at the screen center; But the distance between screen center and tapped-point is not interpreted correctly - it seems to be scaled down by some factor. E.g. tap on screen center gives [0,0], tap on left screen edge should give ~[-3600,0], but instead gives [-1.13,0]. Panning the view such that the previously touched point is in the screen center gives ~[-3600,0], as it should.

Can this be due to the scaling of the scene by 0.001? I have tested various configurations (moving scaling before gluLookAt, or entirely removing it), but the problem persists :(

---

**Sample data output for touch at left screen edge:**

Touch point passed to unproject():

```
x=3, y = 554 (0,0 at bottom left; w=720, h=1280)
```

Projection matrix:

```
[2.8482616, 0.0,       0.0,         0.0, 
 0.0,       1.7320509, 0.0,         0.0, 
 0.0,       0.0,      -1.0001999,  -1.0, 
 0.0,       0.0,      -0.20001999,  0.0]
```

Model matrix:

```
[0.0010, 0.0,    0.0, 0.0, 
 0.0,    0.0010, 0.0, 0.0, 
 0.0,    0.0,    1.0, 0.0, 
 0.0,    0.0,    1.0, 1.0]
```

unproject() output:

```
[-1.1232367, -0.11801138, -1.0032262, 1.0]
```

What comes to my mind here is that the returned z value seems to be wrong - the z value passed into unproject() is -30 (as mentioned above).

Comment: Does the [MatrixGrabber](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/spritetext/MatrixGrabber.html) contain the correct matrices? Viewport correct? It looks weird though that homogeneous coordinates are used down to model coordinates.

Comment: My MatrixGrabber has valid matrices - don't know if they are ok. Viewport is always [0,0,w,h]. Can you give me a tip regarding homogeneous -> model coordinates?

Comment: No this is OK. Projective parts come from projection matrices, and all other affine matrices are built s.t. these parts are passed-through. My guess is that the scale somehow is not present in the grabbers's `mModelView`. For the matrix manipulation calls given in your example, can you show the two grabber matrices, and the `xyzw` output directly after `gluUnProject`?

Comment: updated the question with the sample values you requested :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see -- I wasn't able to reproduce the values you got, however I think this does not matter.

You must not call `unproject` with z-values not within `[-1;+1]`. The first thing `unproject` must do is reverse the windowing transform, and after that, the coordinates must be in NDC-space. In OpenGL, this is the cube `[-1;+1]^3` ([songho](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) contains some nice graphics). Calling `unproject` with `-30` means that the point must have been before the near plane. Calling it with `z=-1.0f` results in the near plane, and `z=+1.0f` in the far plane.

How to choose `z` s.t. after all matrix inversions, `z=-30` holds  -- I don't know.

Comment: man, you are my hero, totally saved my day/week! setting winz to -1 gives a z-value of -1.05, and a winz of 1 gives a z-value of -1001.5 (with corresponding x,y values). given both points, I can calculate a ray and intersect it with my quads. thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to hear that! I (used to) love this type of math, even waded through [Jim Blinn's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Blinn) articles and books. If you think you know stuff, he _will_ twist it ;)